# Find if one of substrings is present in a string without spaces using regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if one of the multiple substrings is present in a string using regex in Java.

```
SomeString: randomtextrickmortysummergazorpazorp
Output needed: true
```

I tried with pattern below but it returns false

```
String patternString = "rick|morty";
String text = "randomtextrickmortysummergazorpazorp";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

System.out.println("Matches :" + matcher.matches());
```

Kindly help.

Comment: use `.find()` instead of `.matches()`

Comment: Thanks @Anubhava, that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `matches()` only returns `true`, if the whole string matches your pattern. Use `find()` instead:

[*matches()*:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches())

> Attempts to match the **entire** region against the pattern.

```
System.out.println("Found :" + matcher.find());
```

[*find()*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()):

> Attempts to find the **next subsequence** of the input sequence that matches the pattern.

Comment: thanks Christian , that worked. You guys saved me wasting time on this small detail.